# How to update a nested object in observable?

Tags: observable, nativescript

I have an observable with a nested object like this

```
signupVM = new observableModule.fromObject({
    editIcon: "\ue3c9",
    editingMode: false,
    signupVal: {
        name: settings.getString("userName"),
        phone: "",
        altPhone: "",
        businessName: "",
        businessAddress: ""
    },
});
```

I'm trying to set the value of `phone` later in my code but its not updating the observable. Here's what I tried:

```
signupVM.set("signupVal.phone", response.data.phone);
signupVM.set("phone", response.data.phone);
```

None of them work. How can I do this?

Comment: Try creating your observable with `fromObjectRecursive` method. e.g signupVM = new observableModule.fromObjectRecursive({...}). This will make the child elements Observable as well. Then you can try to update the value as follows: `signupVM.signupVal.phone =  response.data.phone`

Comment: I tried but `signupVal` is being used by RadDataForm and it breaks.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't exactly remember what it was but I've solved the problem by preloading the data into the observable and not setting it later.

Comment: I had some time to try it out and here's the error: `Binding error while setting property source of RadDataForm<signupForm>@file:///app/signup/signup-page.xml:10:5;: Error: java.lang.Error: DataFormTextEditor does not support properties of type JSONObject. Please specify a value converter for your property.`

Answer (score 0):

Each field needs to be an observable for the change to be reflected in the View layer.

You will need to call NativeScripts notify function.

I use Typescript so doing in pure JS will be slightly different:

```
this.notify({
        eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent,
        propertyName: name,
        object: this, // the property that will be changed
        value: val // new value to be displayed, may be different then the actual prop value
    });
```

Decorator solution (TS):

```
// property of a TS class
 @ObservableProperty() style: string;

function ObservableProperty() {
    return (target: Observable, propertyKey: string) => {
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get() {
                return this["_" + propertyKey];
            },
            set(value) {
                if (this["_" + propertyKey] === value) {
                    return;
                }

                this["_" + propertyKey] = value;
                this.notifyPropertyChange(propertyKey, value);
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to assign a value to `phone`, not bind it to the view layer.